# Poles and Residue

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I have the function $f(z)=(1-e^2z)/z^4$ which i have calculated to have a pole at $z=0$ of order 3.

How would I calculate the residue of this? I have the taylor expansion and am aware you can take the coefficient of $z^-1$ to be the residue and I have answer for that but how would I actually calculate this?

I would know how to do this if, for example, the pole on this function was of order 4 but I've worked it out to be order 3 so this has confused me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Can I take it that that you mean $e^{2z}$ rather than $e^2z$? (Use braces, { }, to surround terms in the exponent.)

You say you "have the Taylor expansion" and ask "how would I actually calculate this?"  Are you saying that you do not know how to find a Taylor series expansion?  Do you know that the Taylor series, about x= 0, is $1+ x+ x^2/2+ x^3/3!+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ x^n/n!+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$?  If not, do you know the [b]definition[/b] of Taylor series (about x= 0- also called a "McLaurin series")? If you so not know any of those things, you need to learn them before you would understand any response to this question.

If you do, then you can calculate that the Taylor's series for $e^{2z}$ is $1+ (2z)+ 4z^2/2+ 8z^n/n!+ \cdot\cdot\cdot+ 2^nz^n/n!+ \cdot\cdot\cdot$.

Now, to get the Taylor series, about x= 0, of $\frac{1- z^{2n}}{z^4}$, subtract from 1, to get $-2z- 4z^2/2- 8z^3/3!- \cdot\cdot\cdot- 2^nz^n/n!-\cdot\cdot\cdot$, then divide each term by $z^4$:
$-\frac{2}{z^3}- 4z^{-2}/2- 8z^{-1}/3!- \cdot\cdot\cdot- 2^nz^{n-4}/n!- \cdot\cdot\cdot$.

The coefficient of $z^{-1}$ is $-8/3!= -8/6= -4/3$.

Comment: Hi, I did mean $e^{2z}$ and I meant that I have the exact workings as you do, I just meant why can you take the $z^{-1}$ term as the residue? I understand that is what you do and I too go the answer of $-4/3$ Is there like a method behind it?

Comment: or reasoning behind it?*

Answer (score 0):

The residue of a pole at $\alpha$ is the coefficient of $(z-\alpha)^{-1}$ in the Laurent expansion about the pole. Your function $f$ (if you have written it correctly; see user247327's answer) is its own Laurent expansion about the origin: $f(z) = \frac{1}{z^4} - e^2 \frac{1}{z^3}$; there's no $1/z$ term, so the residue of the pole at the origin is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

**You** said that you had determined that this function had "a pole of order 3 at z= 0.  So what is you **definition** of "pole of order 3"?